# Scala: why in currying, we can omit the parameters?

Tags: scala

I have a program as below, I can run it without problem using `sum(x=>x)(1,2)` for example.

What I don't understand is that why we can write `sumF` at the very end line, without parameters? I don't find explications about this.

Thanks.

```
def sum(f: Int => Int) : (Int, Int) => Int = {
  def sumF(a:Int, b:Int) : Int = {
    if (a > b) 0
    else f(a) + sumF(a + 1, b)
  }
  sumF
}
```

Comment: If you will see how we are calling the sun function you will get to know we are not omitting the parameters we are giving a and b as 1,2 and the return type of sum is a function of type sumF so what’s the confusion?

Answer (score 4):

The return value of the `sum` function is a function of type

```
(Int, Int) => Int
```

which is what `sumF` is

> In Scala, if there is no return then the last expression is taken to be the return value. So, if the last expression is what you want to return, then you can omit the return keyword

What you are looking at is a higher order function. `sum` is a function that takes in a function `f` as its parameter and returns an arity 2 function that takes 2 ints and returns an Int (which is the exact type signature of `sumF`).

Comment: I used to think sumF is the tail recursion

Comment: `sumF` does not use tail recursion, you would need to re-work the code a bit for that.